# Where is this git tag associated with a commit coming from? How to understand it on the version control history?

Tags: git, github, version-control, tags, magit

I would like to understand better the git commits associated with tags.

For context reasons, there is a public repository called `deg/re-frame-firebase` ([link](https://github.com/deg/re-frame-firebase)).
My doubt actually arises from **a fork** of this repository which is called: `tallyfor/re-frame-firebase` ([link](https://github.com/tallyfor/re-frame-firebase))

On the fork, there is this tag `v0.10.0`. Here is the [information](https://github.com/tallyfor/re-frame-firebase/releases/tag/v0.10.0) on it.

There are some points that I do not understand.

1. After clicking on the commit associated to the tag (which is `bd60d55`), I can see the [changes made](https://github.com/tallyfor/re-frame-firebase/commit/bd60d55815b6168210049510bb5d033301de3cb8). As indicated on the GitHub UI, it is one line change on a file called: `src/com/degel/re_frame_firebase/storage.cljs`. The weird thing, though, is that I **cannot** find this file. The file path **does not** exist on the master branch of the [fork](https://github.com/tallyfor/re-frame-firebase/tree/master/src/com/degel/re_frame_firebase) nor on the master branch of the [original](https://github.com/deg/re-frame-firebase/tree/master/src/com/degel/re_frame_firebase) repository. Where is this file coming from?
2. The second thing is that I can access version `v.0.10.0` via `git checkout`:

[image]

However, the tag is not shown on the `git log` of master branch:

[image]

Hence, since it is *not* on `master branch`, I assume it is on a different branch, coming from a Pull Request. But there is no Pull Request [about it](https://github.com/tallyfor/re-frame-firebase/pulls).

Where is this coming from?

Comment: Commits come from commands that make commits. What commits are called in this repo or that has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step in the Zen of Git here is to realize that *branches and tags do not matter*.  The only things that really matter are the *commits*.

> After clicking on the commit associated to the tag (which is `bd60d55`)

More precisely, it is commit `bd60d55815b6168210049510bb5d033301de3cb8`.

*That* is the name of the commit.  Forget about branch names and tag names, at least for now: `bd60d55815b6168210049510bb5d033301de3cb8` *is* the commit.

If you have a Git repository and your Git repository has `bd60d55815b6168210049510bb5d033301de3cb8` in it, it has *that* commit in it.  *Any* Git repository, anywhere on earth, that has commit `bd60d55815b6168210049510bb5d033301de3cb8` in it, has *that* commit.  Any Git repository that does not have `bd60d55815b6168210049510bb5d033301de3cb8` *does not have that commit*.

If at this point you can remember `bd60d55815b6168210049510bb5d033301de3cb8` now and forever, that's all you need.  But if you're like me, you probably don't remember `bd60d55815b6168210049510bb5d033301de3cb8` even after you paste it seven times.  *That's* when a *name*, like `v0.10.0`, is useful: if you can remember *that*, Git will—under the right conditions, which are easy to achieve—use that to find the big ugly hash ID that I've already forgotten.  And *that* will find the *commit*, and now you're done.  It's the commit that matters, and Git *needs* the hash ID, and you can remember the tag name instead of the hash ID.

> The weird thing, though, is that I **cannot** find [the file named `src/com/degel/re_frame_firebase/storage.cljs`.

Files, in Git, are stored in commits.  If you can find the commit, that's where you'll find the file.  Technically, the commit itself contains just some metadata that allow Git to find the *tree* objects that allow Git to translate the file name to a blob hash ID that finds the blob object that holds the file's content—but you don't need to know all that.  What you *do* need to know is that it's the commit hash ID, plus the path name, that get you this.

> The second thing is that I can access version `v.0.10.0` via `git checkout` ...

You can get to the *commit* with `git checkout` or `git switch --detach`, both of which will fill in your *working tree* from the full contents of that particular commit.

Each commit, in Git, holds a full snapshot of every file, frozen in time, as of the form it had at the time whoever *made* the commit, made that commit.

(Internally, these are stored as *blob objects* found via *tree objects* found via the commit metadata found via the commit.  These objects themselves are stored compressed and de-duplicated, so every commit that shares some particular version of some particular data literally *shares* that file-version with every other commit that has the same data.  Furthermore, objects are often delta-compressed against other objects—but this happens invisibly, below the level at which commits, trees, and objects exist.  So again you don't really need to know all of this: you can just be assured that Git usually does a fairly good job of storing every version of every file ever committed without wasting much disk space.)

Each commit lists, in its metadata, the hash ID(s) of some *previous* ("parent") commit(s).  In this particular case, commit `bd60d55815b6168210049510bb5d033301de3cb8` has one parent, which is commit `432dac15092af1b8681a5cc4e69cb93433f3a5fc`.  All of the files inside each of these two commits match *except for* the file named `src/com/degel/re_frame_firebase/storage.cljs`, which has the one typo fixed in the newer commit.  A lot of Git viewers—including `git log` and GitHub's web browser view—"like to" show you the *differences* between the non-matching files, since that's usually what humans like to see.

> Since [this particular commit] is not on `master branch`, I assume it is on a different branch ...

It *could* be on one or more branches.  It could be on *no* branch.  As long as you memorize its hash ID, you can find it that way, and if you don't know its hash ID, you can use some other name to find it.

#### Once you grok the above, it's time for a few last questions

Philosophical question: if you can't find it, does it exist?  ("It" here is probably a commit, but this applies to everything where the pronoun fits.)

Practical question: If it had existed at one point, but you couldn't find it then and can't find it now, and Git may or may not have deleted it, does it exist?

The point of *branch names* is that they help you—and Git—find the *latest* commit "on" some branch.  Any commit can be "on" any number of branches, from "none" to infinity (if you can create an infinite number of branches anyway), but the very definition of a branch name is that whatever commit hash ID it holds, *that* commit *is* the *latest* commit on the branch.  So whatever hash ID is in some branch name, that's the *last* commit.  From here, Git uses the stored parent hash ID(s) to work backwards in time.

The point of *tag names* is that they help you and Git find *one specific commit*.  This is the same as a branch name!  However, there's no corresponding "by definition" part here: a tag attached to a commit hash ID doesn't imply anything special about the commit, other than "some human thought it was worth giving a human-readable name".  Since these names are assigned *by* humans, for human purposes, there's not too much more to say here, except that Git makes a somewhat feeble attempt to keep humans from re-assigning the same tag name to a different commit later.  That attempt is easy to override, but if you do it, remember that not everyone will pick up the update.  By contrast, people who pick up branch names are *expected* to *assume* that the branch name will "move" over time, since the commit that is "the latest" changes over time.

You now understand Git branching!

Answer (score 2):

1. Any Git's changeset can be tagged
2. Tallyfor's repo have a lot of branches
3. Any feature, planned for upstream, will be coded in separate branch of form for traceability
4. Page of tag on GitHub contains *all* information of its branch `2-fix-project-name-add-prefix-tallyfor`

[image: Branch of tag]